# How to view newest app releases in the iOS App Store app?

Tags: app-store

In the iOS App Store app, is there a way to view newest app releases...that is, a "sort by release date" view?

(I seem to recall seeing this in the past, but I can't find that functionality now.)

When I release my app, will it appear in some "release date"-sorted view? For example if I were to release my app tomorrow, would it appear in such a list?

Thanks.

-Allan